# invoke virtual method com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object

Tags: android

I have a problem when I run my project it gives me this error message

```
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.jawaher.ff.activities.QuizActivity$4.onFinish(QuizActivity.java:377)
```

Here is a screenshot for the full error code
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfXly.png)

the line of the code that says it have a problem

```
watchAdBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

and here is the part of the code

```
else if (userLives == 0 && questionAttempted <questionLimit){

                        Log.d(TAG,"Question attempted "+questionAttempted);
                        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(QuizActivity.this);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rewarded_ad_dialogue_layout);
                        TextView title = dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView16);
                        title.setText("No Lives");
                        MaterialButton watchAdBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.watchAdBtn);
                        MaterialButton endQuizBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.endQuizBtn);

                        //Ad for wrong answer
                        //Showing Ad for lives
                        watchAdBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                displaySuccessToast("Please wait loading Ads");

                                Call<FetchAppSettings> fetchRewardedAdId = ApiController.getInstance().getApi().getAppSettings();

                                fetchRewardedAdId.enqueue(new Callback<FetchAppSettings>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(Call<FetchAppSettings> call, Response<FetchAppSettings> response) {
                                        FetchAppSettings result = response.body();
                                        int errorCode = result.getErrorCode();
                                        String message = result.getMessage();
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the error into the question instead of showing a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is only happening because your MaterialButton

> MaterialButton watchAdBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.watchAdBtn);

is returning a null object, because it didn't find the watchAdBtn inside the `rewarded_ad_dialogue_layout.xml` file. Your XML should have something like this, at least:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/watchAdBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: here is the content in rewarded_ad_dialogue_layout.xml :

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/mWatchAdBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"

is everything right ?

Comment: the ID is wrong. The id must be watchAdBtn and your are setting as mWatchAdBtn.